# Assigning a variable to the value of a single element of an array/matrix in Trinket

Tags: python

I'm new to Stack Overflow and to Python (but not new to programming)

Question  - why does Trinket display the run time error -

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for Add: 'int' and 'list' on line 20 in main.py
```

It seems to me it thinks `l_score` is a list even though I have specifically defined is as int within the subroutine.
How can I assign a variable to an element of an array and keep the variable type as it has been assigned e.g. int?
I have marked the part of the code where this error occurs (and alternatives I have tried)

```
# A program to total 3 input numbers

m_score = []
total = 0


def input_scores(): # def = define.
    for i in range(0,3):
      i_score = int(input("score"))
      m_score.append([i_score])
    #end for    
    return m_score # returns the value to the calling line
# end input_scores

def CalculateMean(m_score): # def =  define. 
    tot = 0
    l_score = int(0)
    for i in m_score:
      l_score = (m_score[1])
      tot = tot + l_score            # - QUESTION 
#      tot = tot + int(l_score)       This doesn't work either
#       tot = sum(m_score)          This doesn't work either 

      print('tot = ' + str(tot)) 
      return(tot)
    #end for
    return(total)
#end   CalculateQuartiles

input_scores()
for i in m_score:
  print(i)
#end for

total = CalculateMean(m_score)
print('Total = ' + str(total))
```

Comment: @VasilisG.: `l_score = (m_score[1])` does not assign a tuple. Surrounding a single element in parentheses does not create a tuple; that requires commas.

Comment: @dpwilson oops my bad. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You are appending a list in `m_score.append([i_score])` while you should append an `int`, that is: `m_score.append(i_score)`.

Comment: That worked - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`m_score` is currently a list of lists, so `m_score[1]` is still a list, albeit with a single item. You define it as an empty list in line 1, and later append to it a single-item list.

Change `m_score.append([i_score])` to `m_score.append(i_score)`.